# Como fazer um texto que ao ser clicado abra um áudio na mesma página?

Tags: html, css, aplicação-web, áudio, texto

Eu quero fazer um texto que quando clica toca algum áudio (mas que não abra em outra página) clicou na palavra tocou o áudio tenho esta dúvida em html eu já tentei fazer um link porém quando clica abre em outra aba.
já tentei isto:

```
<a href="Algum áudio.mp3"> alguma coisa</a>
```

Comment: Eu alterei o título da questão no intuito de aumentar o alcance de sua pergunta, pois em quase dois anos teve apenas 72 visitas. Caso não esteja de acordo com a modificação a qualquer momento você poderá ir ao [histórico da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/492828/revisions) e reverter a modificação.

Answer (score 2):

O elemento HTML [`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a), ou elemento âncora, com o atributo [href](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href) cria um hyperlink nas páginas web. Veja a orientação a respeito do uso desses elementos como se fossem botões:

> Elementos âncora são frequentemente usados como botões falsos,
> definindo seu atributo `href` como `#` ou `javascript:void(0)` para
> evitar que a página seja atualizada e, em seguida, ouvindo seus
> eventos de clique .
>
> Esses valores de `href` falsos **causam um comportamento inesperado**
> ao copiar/arrastar links, abrir links em uma nova guia/janela, marcar
> como favoritos ou quando o JavaScript estiver carregando, apresentar
> erros ou estiver desabilitado. Eles também transmitem semântica
> incorreta para tecnologias assistivas, como leitores de tela.
>
> Use um  em vez disso. **Em geral, você deve usar apenas
> um hiperlink para navegação em uma URL real**.
> <sub>Font: [MDN- Elemento  onclick events](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#onclick_events)</sub>

Então use um elemento `<button>` estilizado para tocar um audio embutido com o elemento [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) e acionado pelo método [`HTMLMediaElement.play()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play)

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const audio = document.querySelector("audio");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  audio.play()
});
```

```css
button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  display: inline;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  outline-offset: 0;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

button:hover{
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<span>Você sabe o que é Robobozo?<br> Clique <button>aqui</button> para descobrir.</span>
<audio src="https://incompetech.com/music/royalty-free/mp3-royaltyfree/Robobozo.mp3">
 Seu navegador não suporta o elemento<code>audio</code>.
 </audio>
 
 
 <!-- Robobozo Kevin MacLeod (incompetech.com)
Licensed under Creative Commons: By Attribution 3.0 License
http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/-->
```